# how to create table relationship in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing project management application using laravel 5.2 and in my app user can create projects and each project have many tasks and each task have many sub tasks as well. in my table project and task table have following relationship. 
task model relationship with project model is

```
public function project()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }
```

project model relationship with task table

```
public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

I need subtasks table to store sub tasks and my now My subtask table as following

```
id    subtask  task_id   project_id
1       abc       2           1
2       dfg       2           1
3       frt       3           2
```

how can I create subtasks model in relationship with project and task table?

**Updated**
please see my subtask migration file

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('subtasks', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
                $table->longText('subtask_name');
                $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('task_id')
                      ->references('id')->on('task')
                      ->onUpdate('cascade')
                      ->onDelete('cascade');
            });
        }
```

Comment: need some help guide?

Answer (score 0):

User and Project table has many to many relation ship. Because each user can create many projects and a project may belong to many user.

Project and Tasks has one to many relation ship. Because each Project has many Tasks and a Task belongs to a Project

Tasks and SubTasks has one to many relation ship. Because each Task can have many Subtasks and a Subtask belongs to each user.

In **User.php** (Model)

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
}
```

In **Project.php** (Model)

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tasks::class);
}
```

In **Task.php** (Model)

```
public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function subtasks(){
    return $this->hasMany(SubTask::class);
}
```

In **SubTask.php** (Model)

```
public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Usage think that you have a task and want to know all the subtasks that it has.

For Eg: Just for the sake of demonstration I am doing from command line using tinker.

```
php artisan tinker

$task = App\Task:whereId(1)->get(); //Get the task details with id 1

$task->subtasks; //This will fetch all the subtasks that belongs to the task
```

Comment: actually in this case I need this relationship between subtasks and tasks and project. please can you read my question again

Comment: @Lilan Can you please check now. If any query please revert back. I will give my best shot.

Comment: in my case do we not need a relationship between Project model and Subtasks model?

Comment: No its not the relation ship between Project and Subtasks. Its the relation between Project and Task. As per your question each Project -> has Many Tasks and each Tasks -> has Many subTasks

Comment: ok please see my updated question and see my subtask  migration file and check is it correct or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156190/discussion-between-lilan-and-channaveer-hakari).